# SQL query to get the Sum of all column values in the last row in access table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table like below. I want to sum **parts** column and write the total after the last record. how to specify total and the result in SQL query.

```
Model     parts

Model1    4 
Model2    2
Model3    6
Model4    5
Model5    7
Total     24
```

Comment: An Access report would do this for you automatically if you grouped by models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/608718b/1)

```
SELECT  models, parts
FROM    your_table
UNION
SELECT  'Total' AS models, SUM(parts) AS parts from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION` query to present the detail data with an additional row to present the summary.

```sql
SELECT 0 AS order_by, Model, parts
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS order_by, 'Total' AS Model, Sum(parts) AS parts
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```